# What is the meaning of the different types of brackets/parentheses/braces used in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to grasp the meaning of the different types of brackets/parentheses/braces used in C# and what the rules are or purpose of using different types in different situations.

Currently I have no trouble using the brackets/parentheses/braces but I feel as though I use them on a case-by-case basis without really grasping "why" I am using them and I would like to get an understanding of this.

Just for example, these are instances where I would use the brackets/parentheses/braces:

```
if(Row.Cells[0].Value != null)
{
   listThings = new List<thing>();
   //More code here
}
```

I would really appreciate any kind of explanation as to the rules behind the brackets and what the pattern is behind its uses and how the brackets/parentheses/braces are interpreted by the program.

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Brackets are part of the language syntax.  You use them because that's what the syntax calls for.  Different brackets mean different things, but to get more information about what you should really read the syntax documentation.

Comment: Which "brackets" are you talking about? People generally call `()` "parentheses" (although some people call them "brackets"), call `[]` "brackets" or "square brackets", call `{}` "braces" or "curly braces" (but never "brackets"), and call `<>` "angle brackets".

Comment: Because you can lose the context of every single line of code associated to if / do / while. Including curly bracket help you to read your and others code, and increase code readability, that is valuable for professional coding.

Comment: I'm sorry if the responses you are getting seem harsh. However, you are essentially asking for a tutorial of the C# syntax, and that is not what SO is for.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all

Comment: I think there are too many detailed cases to list them all. I'd probably miss a few if I tried.

Comment: I have googled this problem and I have found little in answer to my question that I understand, hence why I wanted to ask SO to get a simpler answer that I would have more hope in understand. In response to previous comments, I apologise for not knowing the different names of () {} etc, I have edited my post to amend for this but still do not know the term for <>.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Curly brackets `{}` are used to group statements. In your case, the `then` clause of a standard `if - then` statement is wrapped in `{}` to group the statements together.

---

Square brackets `[]` are used for arrays, indexers, and attributes.

`cells[0]` means *"Cell with index of 0"*, which in a more practical sense would mean *"first cell"*.

---

Parentheses `()` are used to specify casts or type conversions:

```
double x = 1234.7;
int a;
a = (int)x; // Cast double to int
```

As well as invoking methods or delegates:

```
TestMethod();
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by [itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86) in the comments, `()` are also used for iteration statements like `for()`, `foreach()`, etc, and namespace keywords like `using()`, etc.

---

Angle Brackets `<>` are used to specify a type argument.

`listThings = new List<thing>();` specifies a list of type `thing`

Comment: I appreciate you spending the time to answer this,in terms that are easy to understand since I've had no luck in finding out through google searches and the results I found were difficult for me to understand (also not knowing the names of the different types of  () {} etc). Do you know what the purpose/meaning of the <> is also? (If you could provide the word for it, I would be immensely grateful). Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

{} express a code block, a sequence of instructions and define a sort of context, for instance a variable defined inside a {} block is not visible outside it.

[] are used to access arrays of objects, in order to get the n-th element of it

() express a condition or an expression, for instance they can be used to group some math expressions, or they can also define the parameters of a function, i.e. add(int a, int b)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are for grouping statements. Parentheses are for grouping and wrapping expressions. Square brackets `[]` are the "indexing" operator. You use them to get some element from another element, typically a collection like a list, array, or dictionary.

In some cases, you don't need curly braces if you are going to use only one statement. For example,

```
if(Row.Cells[0].Value != null)
    listThings = new List<thing>();
    //No more conditional code
//Code that executes regardless of whether the if statement was true.
```