# What is the name of the generic parameter holder?

Tags: java, c#, generics

For example: `class MyList<T>`
What are these <> called? I call them diamond braces but I can't find any reference to that terminology. And I would assume they have a name other than "less than and greater than symbols" since they convey a different meaning. They must have a name. These have names:
( ... ) - parenthesis
[ ... ] - brackets/braces
{ ... } - curly brackets/curly braces

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/angle_bracket

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a different stack exchange website: https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [What is the meaning of the different types of brackets/parentheses/braces used in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748167/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-different-types-of-brackets-parentheses-braces-used-i). It's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic class is defined with the following format:

class name { /* ... */ }

The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameter (also called type variable) T.
This pair of angle brackets, <>, is informally called the diamond.